# Contact in Google regarding actions?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-developers-console

Recently our certification has been rejected, however we feel the reason we are being given isn't justified. Some languages pass and some fail enough though the same intents are used throughout...

Does anyone have contact details for someone in Google who works on actions so I could reach out to them directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle issues with the review process is to reply back to the message from the review team. If you feel an issue isn't justified, then you should explain your reasons in detail why you disagree with their assessment.

However, keep in mind that conversational actions [will be shut down](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset) on June 13 2023.